# Compilation error for Linux kernel module programming

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module, beagleboneblack

I am learning Linux kernel module programming. I am using Beaglebone black for that. I have made simple 'Hello World' application and makefile. I have checked my makefile it's proper. But when I command 'make', it gives me following error:

```
root@beaglebone:/home/sonu# make
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 2.2e+02 s in the future
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.13-bone70/build M=/home/sonu modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.8.13-bone70/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Though I referred some websites. But, all they are asking me to install packages. As I am a newbie. I don't even know how to configure and start internet connection on Beaglebone using ethernet. Please help me I am stuck. Thanks in advance.

**Code is:**

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>

static int __init hello(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Hello World!");
   return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Bye");
}

module_init(hello);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

**Makefile is:**

```
obj-m+=Hello.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
        $(CC) Hello.c -o test
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
        rm test
```

Comment: You ask for help, yet you don't give the Makefile itself (assumption about it being correct is *probably* wrong) and there's also no code (which probably isn't too bad, as the fault lies in the Makefile).

Comment: @tambre I have cross checked my makefile many times. I am sure there is no fault in it. For your convenience, I have attached code. Go through it.

Comment: Better. Always a good idea to attach it even if you think no fault is in it -
 it could be useful for understanding what's going on. Now, does the `/lib/modules/3.8.13-bone70/build` directory exist?

Comment: "Modification time in the future" messages from Make are usually caused by storing files on a network filesystem that's not properly time-synchronized with your build machine.  Ask the administrators of both machines to make sure that their NTP clients are working correctly.

Comment: @tambre No it doesn't exist. I tried finding solutions from other sources. All they are saying is to install package. But, to install that package all I need is internet connection. So as far as now is concern, I don't know how to configure internet on beaglebone using ethernet i.e, how and which changes to make. Apart from that, I am using 'PuTTy' to access beaglebone.

Comment: @Toby Can you please elaborate? What is NTP client?

Comment: That's the Network Time Protocol, that both machines need to be using, if you want them to share a consistent idea of file timestamps.  As I say, ask your system administrator(s), who will know immediately what to look at.

Comment: Since the mod time is only 220 seconds in the future, if the admins are not able to fix the system times, you could also wait 4 minutes and try again.

Comment: you say 'Though I referred some websites. But, all they are asking me to install packages. As I am a newbie. I don't even know how to configure and start internet connection on Beaglebone using ethernet.' Please start by the beginning and learn how to before trying kernel hacking ..

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you're trying to build your module for a kernel version that you haven't installed the headers for.

Instead of calling `uname` directly in your rules, it's helpful to put that into a variable you can override:

```
obj-m+=Hello.o

KSRC := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
        make -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD) modules
        $(CC) Hello.c -o test
clean:
        make -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD) clean
        rm test
```

Now, you can override with the actual location of your kernel headers:

```sh
make KSRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.2 all
```

You can simplify the Makefile further with a catch-all rule:

```
obj-m+=Hello.o

KSRC := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all: modules
        $(CC) Hello.c -o test

%:
        make -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD) $@

clean::
        make -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD) clean
        $(RM) test
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see 'linux-headers-xxx' folder inside /usr/src. Now to resolve this all I need is to install 'linux headers'. But I can't do it without internet connection. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: You'll need to know where the headers are located, for the version you want to build against.  There's not much we can do to find them for you now.

Comment: Any command to find headers? I am stuck. I can't go on further.